# Can't put correct date & time on LXC container with ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ntp, proxmox, date

I'm tryig to put correct date and time, on Proxmox LXC container with ubuntu but I can't. There are some info of my server.

```
➜  ~ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Date and time is not weel:

```
➜  / date
Fri Apr 19 09:15:17 CEST 2019

➜  / timedatectl status
               Local time: Fri 2019-04-19 09:15:27 CEST
           Universal time: Fri 2019-04-19 07:15:27 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a
                Time zone: Europe/Madrid (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: n/a
          RTC in local TZ: no

➜  / sudo hwclock --hctosys --verbose
hwclock from util-linux 2.34
System Time: 1555659408.378273
Trying to open: /dev/rtc0
Trying to open: /dev/rtc
Trying to open: /dev/misc/rtc
No usable clock interface found.
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
```

When I tried to update package repositori i have this error:

```
 / apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 370d 10h 17min 57s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 998d 2h 18min 54s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 998d 2h 18min 20s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks,

Comment: Is the date correct on the host?

Comment: No, on the host a have the same issue. I'm trying to solve host date but i can't. You know how can i put weel date? thnks

Comment: set the date on the host and it will be correct in the container as well. Read the manual of the `date` command and configure an NTP server.

Comment: As it stands, this question is not clear enough; by "weel" do you mean "correct"?  Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Containers are (usually) unable to adjust the hardware clock of the host; you need to make any date changes from the host.

Comment: Thanks at all. I change host date seting a date like this `date --set="yyyymmdd hh:mm"`, and solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The problem was that the date and time of host don't was correct. I change host date seting a date like this `date --set="yyyymmdd hh:mm"`, and solve it, because the the container take date from the host.